# Generic list of lists Java

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

i'm trying to make a generic function in Java to find out the maximum similarity between an ArrayList and a list from an ArrayList of ArrayLists.

```
public static int maxSimilarity(ArrayList<?> g, 
        ArrayList<ArrayList<?>> groups){

    int maxSim = 0;
    for(ArrayList<?> g2:groups){
        int sim = similarity(g, (ArrayList<?>) g2);
        if(sim > maxSim)
            maxSim = sim;
    }
    return maxSim;
}
```

However, when i try to call it in my main function, it show an incompatible error

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Points>> cannot be converted to ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>
```

I don't understand, i tought all objects can be represented by the ? sign. Also, it works in my similarity function, between two ArrayLists:

```
public static int similarity(ArrayList<?> g1, ArrayList<?> g2){
    int total = 0;
    for(Object o1:g1){
        for(Object o2:g2){
            if(o1.equals(o2))
                total++;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: how are you calling `maxSimilarity`?

Comment: maxSimilarity(points, listofpoints)

Comment: where points is ArrayList<Points> and listofpoints is ArrayList<ArrayList<Points>>

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a wildcard, declare a generic value:

```
public <T> static int maxSimilarity(List<T> g, List<? extends List<T>> gs);
```

Comment: Is the `extends` necessary ? Can't we just write `public <T> static int maxSimilarity(List<T> g, List<List<T>> gs);` ? Just asking to be sure ...

Comment: @Autar when you forgo using the `extends` operator it will not accept any type other than `List` explicitly. By including `extends` under the generic you allow for all subtypes as well. You could even put the extends on the `T` declaration itself to allow comparisons of subtypes of `T`, but normally that's extraneous comparing.

Answer (score 2):

Change your method signature to:

```
public static int maxSimilarity(ArrayList<?> g, ArrayList<? extends ArrayList<?>> groups)
```

And in general prefer using interface types, instead of actual implementations (more flexible, less code):

```
public static int maxSimilarity(List<?> g, List<? extends List<?>> groups)
```

[edit] Based on the suggestion with the type variables, to make this super-generic, it should be:

```
public static <T> int maxSimilarity(List<? extends T> g, List<? extends List<? extends T>> groups)
```

Notice that `? extends T`. This way, you can use e.g.

```
List<List<StringBuilder>> groups = // ...
List<String> g = // ...
maxSimilarity(g, groups);
```

(`StringBuilder` and `String` are a `CharSequence`, so they can be compared).

Comment: I don't agree with continuing the use of wildcards for this, it will just add more ambiguity compared to specifying a single type ("`T`")

Comment: @Rogue Depends, but if you really want to introduce type parameters, you should do it like in the edit (reason given).

Comment: @user2977065 The reason is type covariance/contravariance in Java generics. It's a bit too much to explain here in the comments, just Google it or search here on SO. There are good explanations.

Comment: @qqilihq it's not always the case that you want to do `<? extends T>` (especially when not wanting to include subtypes). I glossed over it in reply to a comment on my answer above :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare lists of similar objects, you should introduce a method type parameter

```
public static <T> int maxSimilarity(List<T> g, List<List<T>> groups) {
```

because it's nearly useless comparing completely different objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your method:

```
public static <T>int maxSimilarity(ArrayList<T> g,  ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> groups)
```

Hope it helps.